# How to get the version of gremlin python client on AWS SageMaker

Tags: gremlin, amazon-sagemaker

What is the command to check the version of Gremlin Python client running on a AWS Sagemaker jupyter notebook? I would like to run the command on the jupyter notebook cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a notebook cell you should be able to just ask Pip which version is being used

```
!pip list | grep gremlinpython
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kelvin. I apologize for not acknowledging your help sooner.